# Grep 'OR' regex problem

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to use grep with a regex to find lines in a file that match 1 of 2 possible strings. Here is my grep:

```
$ grep "^ID.*(ETS|FBS)" my_file.txt
```

The above grep returns no results. However if I execute either:

```
$ grep "^ID.*ETS" my_file.txt
```

or

```
$ grep "^ID.*FBS" my_file.txt
```

I do match specific lines. Why is my OR regex not matching? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

With normal regex, the characters `(`, `|` and `)` need to be escaped. So you should use

```
$ grep "^ID.*\(ETS\|FBS\)" my_file.txt
```

You don't need the escapes when you use the *extended regex* (`-E`)option. See `man grep`, section "`Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions`".

Comment: You can also use `egrep` instead of `grep -E`.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri The answer of Michal states that egrep (and fgrep) are deprecated (even though they might still work).

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use multiple branches (the `|` as `or`), then to be more compatible, it's better to explicit say you want to use "modern RE" aka. ERE.

To do so, use **grep -E**:

```
grep -E "^ID.*(ETS|FBS)" my_file.txt
```

To learn more about RE, ERE and the whole "modern" ER story see `man 7 regex`.

Alternatively you can use `egrep` instead of `grep`, but  as you can read from `man grep`:

> egrep is the same as grep -E.  fgrep is the same as grep -F

(...)

> Direct invocation as either **egrep** or **fgrep** is **deprecated**

Comment: While direct invocation of egrep is deprecated it will work in most *nix variants.